# Good news for this site, and possibly a source of search traffic

Tags: discussion

President Obama signed an [executive order for the USA](http://www.whitehouse.gov//sites/default/files/microsites/ostp/2013opendata.pdf) yesterday ordering that "going forward, newly generated government data shall be made freely available in open, machine-readable formats, while  appropriately safeguarding privacy, confidentiality, and security. This requirement will help the Federal government achieve the goal of making troves of previously inaccessible or unmanageable data easily available to entrepreneurs, innovators, researchers, and others who can use those data to generate new products and services, build businesses, and create jobs."

Comment: I don't doubt that the people participating in this beta are interested in this news. But unless you Jeopardy-ize the topic and put it in the form of a question, how can it work in SE's Q-and-choose-the-best-A format?

Comment: @Roger_S it is my understanding that meta can break the rules at times - perhaps I've bent them too far this time, though. I fully agree this would be closed on main.

Comment: biostars.org allow news and job posting as items on stackechange.

Comment: @user56 However, http://biostars.org is not part of the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just the USA, the G8 have just published their [Open Data Charter](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/open-data-charter/g8-open-data-charter-and-technical-annex) where they state things like:

> We recognise that free access to, and subsequent re-use of, open data are of significant value to society and the economy.

We live in exciting times :)

Now all we need is some more users for Open Data SE …